# Is it good/bad practice to store runtime-constant values in a function-locale static variable to speed-up mutliple calls?

Tags: php, performance, caching, architecture

Asume this situation. You have a class with a method that is, for a given instance, always returning the same value (determined by constructor, for example).

```
final class A
{
    private const VALUES = [/*long array*/];

    private $a = 5; // initialized in constructor, immutable afterwards

    public function isSafe(): bool
    {
        return \in_array($this->a, self::VALUES, true);
    }
}
```

Are there any downsides of caching this in a function-local static variable? For example like this:

```
final class A
{
    private const VALUES = [/*long array*/];

    private $a = 5; // initialized in constructor, immutable afterwards

    public function isSafe(): bool
    {
        static $result = null;
        return $result ?? $result = \in_array($this->a, self::VALUES, true);
    }
}
```

What are the pros and cons of this approach? Are there alternatives? Is this considered good, bad or any practice (if so: why)? Or should the "caching" already happen in constructor, for example?

Comment: On a site note, the `ìsSafe()` function will not work correctly when you have multiple instances of the A class. (Only the first call to `ìsSafe()` will return the correct result). After that ***all*** instances of the A class will return the same value from `isSafe()`

Comment: @Turtlefight Oh, seems I made big mistake then. I thought function-locale statics are static wrt. to mutliple calls to the same instance, not globally. Then the answer is obvious: it's bad practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going to use that approach I think it makes more sense to hold that value in a private property rather than in a static variable in the function. After all, it really is a property of the object, albeit a derived property.

```
final class A
{
    private const VALUES = [/*long array*/];

    private $a; // initialized in constructor, immutable afterwards
    private $safe;

    public function isSafe(): bool
    {
        return $this->safe ?? $this->safe = \in_array($this->a, self::VALUES, true);
    }
}
```

---

This will also avoid the problem [@Turtlefight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8411406) mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57083664/is-it-good-bad-practice-to-store-runtime-constant-values-in-a-function-locale-st/57083989#comment100690955_57083664) on your question. (Quoting it here since comments are impermanent.)

> the `ìsSafe()` function will not work correctly when you have multiple instances of the A class. (Only the first call to `ìsSafe()` will return the correct result). After that all instances of the A class will return the same value from `isSafe()`

Comment: Thanks, made a big mistake when thinking about this. I thought function-locale statics are static wrt. to mutliple calls to the same instance, not globally. Then the answer is obvious: it's bad practice (or plain wrong).

Answer (score 2):

Your example is simple enough that it would not justify the use of such buffering. What you are trying to do is optimise the code before facing any performance issues. [Is premature optimization really the root of all evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80092/339200)

There is nothing wrong per se with the use of `static`, but it adds more complexity to your code with barely any tangible results. However if instead of `in_array` you had a DB operation, file read, web service call, or if you called this method in a loop over and over, then caching the result might be a good idea. You need to be sure though, that the buffered value will always be the same for each method call, or have in place a way to invalidate the buffer.

> *"should the "caching" already happen in constructor?"*

No. You should always aim to make your code as lazy as possible. Evaluate the result on the first call of `isSafe()` when it is actually requested instead of doing it prematurely in a constructor.